# Youtube videos after sleep mode

Tags: debian, video, firefox, browser

(This is my first post here, I hope my post is ok)

After sleep mode (close / open laptop screen), if I try to play a video on youtube the video doesn't play and I have this message : "If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device."

But if I open youtube with Chromium and play any video : it plays in Chromium and it even "unlocks" the video in Firefox! (the Firefox video starts playing at the moment I press play on the Chromium video, strange no?)

It is not a big problem but I would like to fix it and I don't understand how and why sleep mode could "locks" videos in Firefox and playing a video in Chromium "unlocks" Firefox videos.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you.

Thinkpad X220
Debian 8.7

Answer (score 0):

I still have this issue on Firefox on OSX86. Looks like a Firefox bug to me.
Works in Chrome and after a reboot.